# SQL - dynamic row and column in output

Tags: mysql

This is my sample query for counting the number of sales by salesman and make a modelname as column for the output.My problem is both salesman and modelname are dynamics.

Any suggestion are welcome.

---------eg query--------------------------

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS bil, a.sales_dt,a.salesman, b.model_name,c.full_name
from t_sales a left join t_carinfo b on a.chasis_no=b.chasis_no,t_user c,(SELECT @rownum:=0) r 
where a.agent_code='03' and a.sname is not null and a.sname='01' and a.salesman=c.regno and YEAR(a.sales_dt)='1995' 
group by  a.salesman, b.model_name
```

----- output ----

```
bil sales_dt salesman model_name full_name 
1 1995-05-29 15 E200 ANUAR 
2 1995-06-30 16 HARRIER AZHAR 
3 1995-09-14 15 HARRIER ANUAR 
4 1995-11-15 17 E200 KAMAL
```

---

desire output:------------

bil     full_name   salesman   HARRIER  E200
1   ANUAR        15         1         1
2   AZHAR        16     1         0
3   KAMAL        17     0         1

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to turn row values like this into dynamic columns you must use `PIVOT`. Check this description: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table[1](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table)

Give it a try, and feel free to post again if you are still not getting the desired result.